# Can create culture for en-EN on local dev machine

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5.2

I just deployed our application to our azure staging environment and ran into an issue with the `en-EN` culture not being supported. After some digging I find out that there is no such culture, and I should use `en-GB` or `en-US`instead.

But, now to my question. On my local development machine I've got no problems creating a `CultureInfo` with `en-EN`.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-EN"); 
Console.WriteLine("culture: "+ ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
```

Outputs `culture: eng`

I also tried enumerating all cultures with `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);` and there's no corresponding `en-EN` culture in the result.

So, what's going on, why can I create a culture which shouldn't exist?

Comment: You can always create a culture which doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you mean? If I run the above snippet on e.g. our staging machine, I get an exception saying the culture isn't supported (which is what I'd expect)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 the culture behaviour has changed: "unkown", but "maybe existing" cultures (3-letter iso) will only result in an "Unkown locale" culture with LCID 4096.
Pre-Windows 10 this would result in an exception (unless you have installed such a custom culture)

[MSDN-Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
        try
        {


            // ok
            CultureInfo culture1 = new CultureInfo("foo");
            CultureInfo culture2 = new CultureInfo("xyz");
            CultureInfo culture3 = new CultureInfo("en-xy");

            // not ok - exception
            CultureInfo culture4 = new CultureInfo("foox");

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky2chs3h(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Starting with apps that run under the .NET Framework 4 or later on Windows 7 or later, the method attempts to retrieve a CultureInfo object whose identifier is name from the operating system; **if the operating system does not support that culture, and if name is not the name of a supplementary or replacement culture, the method throws a CultureNotFoundException exception**.

So basically, your OS has `en-EN` as an alternate name of an existing culture (more likely `en-US`) while it's not there on the Azure VM.

The solution is: use a real culture name (which you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx))