# The locale en-EN is an invalid culture identifier

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-8.1

I recently shifted from a computer which had Windows 10 with VS 2017 to a computer which had Windows 8.1 with VS 2017.
I was working with a piece of code which had a line like this.

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(locale);`

Here, `locale` value is `en-EN`. I got hit with a surprise when this threw a `CultureNotFoundException` exception with a message.

> en-EN is an invalid culture identifier.

Surprising to me because, the same code with `locale` as `en-EN` works in Windows 10.

I have checked for a few solutions.
Does Windows 8.1 not support a few locales? Can the missing locales be added?
Or, is this a problem that is completely unrelated to the OS. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/43115074/1132334

Comment: Yes @dlatikay. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `en-EN` is really an invalid culture identifier. However, in Windows 10 the behavior of handling invalid identifiers [changed a bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1).

You have basically two options:

1. Use a valid identifier. For English in England you should use `en-GB`
2. If your desired England culture differs from `en-GB`, then register a new culture.

This is how you can register a new culture:

Cultures have a hierarchy where the root is always the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Conventionally, culture names reflect this hierarchy. So for example, `en-GB`, which is a region-specific (Great Britain) culture, is derived from `en`, which is the region-independent English culture, and its parent is the invariant culture.

If you want to create an England-specific culture derived from `en-GB`, then you should call it something like `en-GB-England`

```
var parent = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
var builder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("en-GB-England", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
builder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(parent);
builder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo(parent.Name));
builder.Parent = parent;
builder.CultureEnglishName = "English (Great Britain, England)";
builder.CultureNativeName = builder.CultureEnglishName;

try
{
    builder.Register();
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
    // You must run this code with Administrator rights
     throw;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException e) when (e.Message.Contains("already exists"))
{
    // culture is already registered
}

var enEN = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB-England");
```

Comment: Thank you @taffer. This answers my question. Also, +1 for the link and the options. :)

Comment: With my pedant's hat on, I'd like to point out that `England` != `Great Britain`.

Comment: @awj: Yes, that's why in the example England's registered culture was a specialized one derived from `en-GB` (see that `en-GB` is set as a `Parent` culture for the newly registered one).

Comment: Ah, I've got it now. Sorry.