# Dynamic custom culture info

Tags: c#, datetime-format, cultureinfo

I'm working on a .net web application. The user is able to change language and country individually. Now how can I create a valid culture based upon these values for use with DateTimeFormat?

The language and country is added dynamically so in the end the user could possibly select all kinds of different variants. Like:

en-SE, sv-FI, en-RU

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code? Is the problem that some combinations are non-existing cultures? If so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810346/5114784) may help to register new ones. But what's `us-RU` supposed to mean? The first part needs to be a language (eg. `en`) rather than a country.

Comment: Yes, potentially the culture "created" by the user is not valid or non-existing. Sorry, my bad, it should be en-RU.

Comment: Correct. And `car1.GregorianDateTimeFormat` gets/sets the `DateTimeFormatInfo` you needed.

Comment: Ok, so if I where to create a custom culture I would need to build it based upon a valid existing culture.

`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder car1 = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("ru-US", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

car1.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"));
car1.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo("en-US"));`

How would I do that? To me it looks like I have to map all of the different options the user possibly can "create" in order to get the "LoadDataFromCultureInfo" and "LoadDataFromRegionInfo"?

Comment: `LoadDataFrom...` just makes it easier that you don't need to initialize every possible setting one by one. Choose a 'close enough' parent and adjust the specific differences (eg. date and time format) on demand.